# Getting button on Footer in Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need to add the button on the right hand side of the footer. I am adding it like this

```
<div data-role="footer" id="ftrMain" name="ftrMain" data-position="fixed">
<h4>Copyright 2011</h4>
<a class="ui-btn-right" data-theme="a"  data-ajax="false" href="/login.php?mode=logout">Logout</a>
</div>
```

I am getting the button but it is coming at the start of the next line. If I change the role to header, the button positions perfectly. Even if I add class="ui-header" in footer div, it comes ok but then it simply doesn't get its position fixed. ('coz it has now both the style ui-footer and ui-header)

How can I put the button on footer on extreme right without sacrificing the data-position? (I need the data-position fixed also)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the footer has a right margin set to 90px by default. You need to override it and make the two controls float, like so:

```
<div data-role="footer" id="ftrMain" style="text-align:center" name="ftrMain" 
    data-position="fixed">
    <h4 style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 65px; margin-right: 0">
        Copyright 2011</h4>
    <a class="ui-btn-right" style="margin: 0.4em; float: right" data-theme="a" 
        data-ajax="false" href="/login.php?mode=logout">
        Logout</a>
</div>
```

P.S. From usability point of view, I would have placed the "Logout" button in the top-right corner of the page rather than in a footer.

Comment: Thanks!! Can I make this Copyright coming in the centre of the footer?

Comment: try again, should be centered now

Answer (score 0):

I found Tsar's answer helpful, though it doesn't seem like most of that markup is necessary. I get the same effect with

```html
<div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
    <a class="ui-btn-right" href="/login.php?mode=logout">Logout</a>
    <h3>Copyright 2011</h3>
</div>
```

(I have only tested this in my desktop browser so far.) Looks like the magic is in the `ui-btn-right` class. There is also a `ui-btn-left`.